# How to display radio or dropdown options from a matrix column

Tags: matrix

I have a Matrix field that has columns that are using cell type "Field Pack - Radio Buttons" and "Field Pack - Dropdown". Each of these has 4 options (Master, Advanced, Intermetiate, Apprentice). If an option is set for these columns, i can get these easily in the matrix pair tag.

Is there a way to access and display the entire option list (Master, Advanced, Intermetiate, Apprentice)? I'm sure there is a way to access this, but i have had no luck.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting to show the values on a page, you could do it with an SQL query, or you could possibly output it using [ExpressionEngine Channel Forms](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_form/)? It's the replacement for SafeCracker. Instead of showing a full form collecting info you could just use it to show the values.